# Highcharts margins before and after data display?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to use Area Stacked Highchart, [here's an example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-stacked) and [jsFiddle demo to play with](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/area-stacked/)

Unfortunately the chart itself generates ugly gaps at the beginning and at the end of the x-axis.

This question has been asked all over again, and looks like the answer is "don't use categories for xAxis, remove them and replace with `type: 'datetime'`. Unfortunately I'm getting categories from back end and I can't do nothing about this. And any other setting like margins, paddings, spacing etc. doesn't seem to work with categories at all.

Does anyone have any clue how to fix that? To be honest it looks more like a serious UI / UX bug to me than something that is supposed to happen. Who needs a chart that starts somewhere else than on its edge?! :)

Need 7 more reputation to post an image, sorry for URL: i.stack.imgur.com/lGxo6.png

In short words: [b]try to remove GAPS from jsFiddles example without deleting categories[/b]. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, that was asked quite a lot, I should prepare auto response for this.

Then answer is to use `datetime` axis OR `linear` axis. You have categories from backend? No problem, just store them in some variable and then edit formatter for labels: http://jsfiddle.net/h7Akd/1/

```
var categories = ['1750', '1800', '1850', '1900', '1950', '1999', '2050'];

...             
        xAxis: {
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            title: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tiickInterval: 1, //force to display categories one by one
            labels: {
                formatter: function(){
                     return categories[this.value];   
                }
            }
        },
```

Now you can edit min and max, using or `xAxis.min/max` or 'xAxis.minPadding/maxPadding`.

Extras:

> To be honest it looks more like a serious UI / UX bug to me than something that is supposed to happen. Who needs a chart that starts somewhere else than on its edge?! :)

You will be surprised.. 
For example use columns and you will see. Rather the question is why can't you update backend to return timestamps (as for dates should be)?

Comment: I've seen this response before, unfortunately it doesn't seem to work in my case. At all. And I can't really change the back end, because... I'm using like 50 other charts that are being generated in the same manner and they just work, perfectly fine. But they're linear and this one has HUGE haps on both sides and nothing seems to help. I will try to post jsfiddle code soon.

Comment: As you can see, my solution doesn't depend on backend. And you don't have to use categorized axis. Linear axis != axis with categories.

Comment: thank you it works like a charm. Although I have another problem, how to access these categories on tooltip now? Because this.x  for FollowerFormatter seems to be 1-2-3-4-5 now instead of 1750/1800/1850/1900/1950/1999/2050? :)

Comment: In formatter use exactly the same solution as for xAxis.labels.formatter: `categories[this.value]` -> `categories[this.x]`.

Comment: This was great advice @PawełFus to not use the "categories" property and instead use the labels formatter function. I then used min: null and max: null to automatically calculate the number of labels on the xaxis and everything worked terrific! Can't thank you enough!